# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)

Tags: html, css, webpack

Древо
[image: Древо]

Ошибка полностью:

```
[./assets/1.jpg] 281 bytes {mini-css-extract-plugin} [built] [failed] [1 error]

    ERROR in ./assets/1.jpg 1:0
    Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
    (Source code omitted for this binary file)
     @ ./scss/index.scss (../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./scss/index.scss) 4:36-62
```

JS: `import './scss/index.scss'`
HTML: `<div class="app"></div>`
CSS:

```
.app {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background: url("../assets/1.jpg");
}
```

WEBPACK-CONFIG

```
const path = require('path')
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin')
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
const isDev = !isProd


const filename = ext => isDev ? `bundle.${ext}` : `bundle.[hash].${ext}`

const jsLoaders = () => {
  const loaders = [
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
      }
    }
  ]

  if (isDev) {
    loaders.push(`eslint-loader`)
  }

  return loaders
}

module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
  mode: 'development',
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill', './index.js'],
  output: {
    filename: filename('js'),
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      '@core': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/core')
    }
  },
  devtool: isDev ? 'source-map' : false,
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    hot: isDev
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: isProd,
        collapseWhitespace: isProd
      }
    }),
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/favicon.ico'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
      }
    ]),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: filename('css')
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: isDev,
              reloadAll: true
            }
          },
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: jsLoaders()
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Путь на картинку по разному указывал и всё тоже самое (иногда такая ошибка:

```
ERROR in ./scss/index.scss (../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./scss/index.scss)
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/1.jpg' in 'C:\Users\Сергей\Desktop\Frontend\Project's\My Portfolio on Pure JS\src\scss'
     @ ./scss/index.scss (../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js!../node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js!./scss/index.scss) 4:36-61
```

)

```
 url("../assets/1.jpg")  url("./assets/1.jpg")  url("assets/1.jpg")  url("src/assets/1.jpg")
```

Я так понимаю, проблема в webpack сборке, но решение не знаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Починил! Всё очень просто. Установил модули: `file-loader` и `url-loader`. И в `webpack.config.js`, в

```
module: {
 rules: [                
   *Сюда вставил код ниже*
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Добавил

```
{
    test: /\.(jpg|png|gif|woff|eot|ttf|svg)/,
    use: {
    loader: 'url-loader', // this need file-loader
    options: {
    limit: 50000
}
```