# React не видит путь к изображению

Tags: reactjs, background, img

Пытаюсь сделать фоновое изображение, но не могу импортировать локальное фото...
Я уже и в одну папку все перенес (что б с путем не запутаться) и через папку public пробовал, и через require пробовал... Ну не видит изображение и все тут...

```
import styled, { createGlobalStyle, css } from 'styled-components';
import bgImage from  '../layout/1.jpg'

export const Container = styled.div`
max-width: 1280px;
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
`;

const Background = styled.div`
    background-image: url(${bgImage});
`
```

[image: не видит изобр]

Может нужно еще какой модуль установить? Вот все что установлено...

```
    {
  "name": "portfolio_nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "next": "10.2.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "styled-normalize": "^8.0.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: import bgImage from  './1.jpg'

Comment: Алексей  Не работает. Всегда одна ошибка...
 


wait  - compiling...
error - ./src/layout/1.jpg
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1254244/module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-10?rq=1 может помочь, нужно настроить конфиг, так как для такого типа файлов не настроен загрузчик

Comment: я устонавливал эти модули... Но у меня нет этого вебконфиг, не могу прописать эти зависимости...

Comment: Если проект стартовал через create-react-app, то конфиг лежит в \node_modules\react-scripts\config\webpack.config.js

Comment: # Алексей.     Перелопатил все папки. Нет такого файла. Вообще странно... Начинаю сдаваться уже...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте фото вставлять не ссылкой, а сразу строкой. То есть, вместо:

```
url(${bgImage})
```

напишите:

```
url("../layout/1.jpg")
```

P.S. проверьте ещё корректность относительности пути.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).